# openjdk 8: error - No public or protected classes found to document

Tags: swing, debian, javadoc, java

I'm on `Debian`, and have already installed `OpenJDK 8` along with the packages `openjdk-8-doc` and `default-jdk-doc`; However I can't view any documentation for the classes of `JDK 8 API`, whenever I specify the class or package name to the `javadoc` utility, which fails to show the doc throwing the following errors:

1. ArrayList case:

   ```
   kais@debian:~$ javadoc ArrayList
   Loading source files for package ArrayList...
   javadoc: warning - No source files for package ArrayList
   Constructing Javadoc information...
   javadoc: warning - No source files for package ArrayList
   javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
   1 error
   2 warnings
   kais@debian:~$ javadoc java.lang.ArrayList
   Loading source files for package java.lang.ArrayList...
   javadoc: warning - No source files for package java.lang.ArrayList
   Constructing Javadoc information...
   javadoc: warning - No source files for package java.lang.ArrayList
   javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
   1 error
   2 warnings
   ```
2. JPanel case:

   ```
   kais@debian:~$ javadoc JPanel
   Loading source files for package JPanel...
   javadoc: warning - No source files for package JPanel
   Constructing Javadoc information...
   javadoc: warning - No source files for package JPanel
   javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
   1 error
   2 warnings
   kais@debian:~$ javadoc javax.swing.JPanel
   Loading source files for package javax.swing.JPanel...
   javadoc: warning - No source files for package javax.swing.JPanel
   Constructing Javadoc information...
   javadoc: warning - No source files for package javax.swing.JPanel
   javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
   1 error
   2 warnings
   kais@debian:~$ javadoc javax.swing
   Loading source files for package javax.swing...
   javadoc: warning - No source files for package javax.swing
   Constructing Javadoc information...
   javadoc: warning - No source files for package javax.swing
   javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
   1 error
   2 warnings
   ```

This seems to me weird, as the installed package `openjdk-8-doc` is supposed to contain the doc required by the `javadoc` ..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javadoc tool is supposed to create Javadoc out of Java source. It's not a tool to show the javadoc of a particular class. The Javadocs of the classes in the JVM is available for download at [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html) or can be browsed [online](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

As you said in your question, you "installed" the docs for your corresponding JDK, so instead of downloading it again or browsing it online, you can change to the "installation directory" of the doc-package and open the `index-html` file that should be there at its root.

Comment: And that was my fault .. Thanks for letting me know. Finally opening "file:///usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-doc/api/index.html" in the browser did the trick.